# Answer that didn't get enough play?

Tags: discussion, votes

Anyone have an answer to a question that just didn't get enough play on the site?  Accepted or otherwise, an answer that you worked on and thought worked really well but didn't get many votes for some reason?

Comment: Borror's statement in chat brought this up, as he had a good point about his answer for the minimum wage question.

Comment: We don't see the phenomenon in full effect yet on skeptics.SE, but on other SE sites, old questions/answers of good quality will get more exposure as new questions are closed as duplicates.

Comment: @Jason. Makes sense yep

Comment: Questions that didn't get enough "love" are randomly bumped up on the front page by Community

Answer (score 1):

This is a general problem of the Stack Exchange sites. Question life is quite short, and if you provide an answer to a question which is not very fresh, the answer is not seen by many people and is unlikely to attract any votes. This is a bit better on Stackoverflow, as there are already many people solving real problems there, and some of them may hit your answer later. This is probably not the case here - this might get better in the future if the site gets more popular.

Comment: I disagree; questions here are typically as permanently interesting as questions on Stack Overflow, and I've got a few Necromancer badges there (definition:  a certain number of votes for an answer given some time (three months?) after the question is asked).

Comment: Still, my claim is most votes (my estimate is over 90 %) for answers are done within two days from asking the question. I am too lazy to prove this by data analysis, but it is possible to do if anyone wishes so. The cause I see is how questions are visible - nobody is voting for answer for questions he does not see.

Comment: If you posted this as a claim ("In my observation, over 90% of votes on Stack Exchange questions are for answers within two days of the question"), would it be on topic on the main site?  Just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

For me, maybe the [addiction question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/981/does-addictive-behavior-exist/1004#1004).  The accepted answer is well written by david but kind of unsourced except for Wikipedia, and is written from a psychological spectrum standpoint.  I tried to make a play for a physically measurable benchmark for addiction.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I posted on [Is it possible to get to the power needed to thrust a rocket so that it can escape from earth?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/is-it-possible-to-get-to-the-power-needed-to-thrust-a-rocket-so-that-it-can-escap) didn't earn any points for my account.

As I write it has over 10 votes.

But it got converted to wiki for some reason. Maybe I used edit too many times.  But, you need to use edit to construct anything long with multiple references....

If it is too big a pain to fix, don't worry about it.

Comment: [Community Wiki mode](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/158693) automatically kicks in after you edit your post at least 10 times or 5 different people edit it.  You keep any reputation you earned before it became CW but you don't gain any afterward.  [Moderators can convert it back at their discretion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2974/158693), so flag it for moderator attention if you so desire.

Comment: @Patches Thanks for the tip